# Подтверждение аккаунта

Tags: java, spring, java-ee

Хочу реализовать подтверждение аккаунта по почте. Но не знаю как это реализовать. В интернете нашел только один гайд. Но там реалиализовано без настройки spring'a . У кого нить есть ссылки где полностью описан процесс?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

я это делал так:

```
1. Создал таблицу в базу данных (поля: id, id_user, token);
2. при отправки подтверждения записываю в созданную таблицу:
   - id_user - это id пользователя
   - token - закодированный текущий таймстемп в md5
3. отправляю на почту пользователя ссылку, с get параметром - http://site.name.com/email_confirm?token={token"}
4. при открытия ссылки, что отправил пользователю - подтверждается почта юзера {id_user}, если {token} существует в таблице.
```